# PHP date.timezone issue - phpinfo shows no value

Tags: php, date, timezone

I am getting following warning:

> It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are
>   *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.

However, I have set value of default time zone in php.ini as follows:

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone="Asia/Kolkata"
```

This error started only after installing xdebug. Not sure xdebug is causing this or not. I have double checked, this is caused by xdebug only but why that I dont know.
Can anyone help to fix xdebug issue related to this?

Comment: Is it in any particular piece of code or everywhere in ur project?

Comment: No, it is defined in php.ini still not showing in phpinfo. I have restarted many time to check the same

Comment: I found detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128558/php-xdebug-issue-date-timezone-session-save-path-undefined