# PHP Xdebug issue - date.timezone & session.save_path undefined

Tags: php, xdebug

After installing and enable xdebug `date.timezone` and `session.save_path` shows no value. If I disable the xdebug, everything works well.

So, why above values becomes empty when I enable xdebug?

Additional Information:

```
xdebug version: 2.2.3
Php version: 5.5
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451719/cannot-set-date-timezone-in-php-ini-file

Comment: Not duplicate, It dont provide the reason why above values become empty

Comment: Please read question carefully and then try to call it duplicate

Comment: I think you can find the answer to your question there. By the way I suppose that what you're looking for is that your xdebug.ini ovverride date.timezone of your php.ini

Comment: Yes, xdebug overrides value of session save path and date timezone both, I wants to know why this happen, I could not find the cause there can you please provide brief why this happens? I also try to add date.timezone in xdebug.ini as suggested, but no luck

Comment: Sorry but I think i don't understand "xdebug overrides value of session save path and date timezone both, I wants to know why this happen". You want understand why xdebug overrides php.ini ?

Comment: I mean, If I enabled the xdebug, timezone save_path shows no value means some how value is not reflected in phpinfo, If i disable xdebug everything works fine. So I wants to know why xdebug causing such scenario

Comment: Because that's how it work. php.inis in projects override your standard php.ini file. So when you enable xdebug you have a new date.timezone value that ovveride your php.ini standard file.

Comment: k, fine you means enabling xdebug I have new values for date.timezone and session.save_path, Where can I find the same? Because it is not mentioned anywhere in xdebug.ini

Comment: Try to append to your xdebug.ini date.timezone = "Something"

Comment: Already tried but no luck as I said earlier. It is not written anywhere in xdebug, so why value overwritten

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution by myself.

All the settings like `date.timezone` and `session.save_path` needs to be initialized before you define/enable xdebug.

It is always better to load xdebug extension at the end of file(php.ini).